# Sqlite CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS not working?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

What am I missing? I can see the database in the Inspector window, but there are no tables. 
I can create the tables in the console and they show up, but they aren't there automatically.

Here's the openDatabase call:

```
<script>var newdb = openDatabase('db2', '1.00', 'DB1', (100 * 1024 * 1024));
```

Here's the call to create the tables if they don't exist:

```
    newdb.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OBSERVATIONS (observation_id unique,     field_id, observation_date, phase_id, magnitude_id, summary)');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (1, "Test Field 1")');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (2, "Test Field 2")');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (4, "Test Field 3")');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO OBSERVATIONS (observation_id, field_id, observation_date, phase_id, magnitude_id, summary, plant_no) VALUES (1, 1, "1/1/2012", 1234, 5678, "This is Observation 1", 100)');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO OBSERVATIONS (observation_id, field_id, observation_date, phase_id, magnitude_id, summary, plant_no) VALUES (2, 1, "1/2/2012", 1234, 5679, "This is Observation 2", 101)');
});
```

Comment: Is there an error you are getting?

Comment: No error in the inspector. It's just not adding the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh. I'm an idiot.

I had the wrong arguments in my insert into observations.